# python selenium click checkbox one by one instead of all together

Tags: selenium, checkbox

```
df3 = list(df2)
for i in df3:  
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//html//body//div[2]//div//div[2]//div[1]//form//div//div[2]//div//div[2]//label[{}]//input".format(i)))).click()
```

I managed to click all selected checkbox by loop over a list but I would like to click the checkbox one by one instead of all together

Comment: The boxes are being check one by one just so fast you cannot see it.  You can use `time.sleep(1)` in the loop to slow it down.

Comment: how to click one by one and unclick it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's happening one by one. It's very fast for humans to see. For seeing it check one by one. You can introduce the delay between the selections by adding `sleep(waitTimeInSeconds)` as shown below

```
import time

df3 = list(df2)
for i in df3:       
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//html//body//div[2]//div//div[2]//div[1]//form//div//div[2]//div//div[2]//label[{}]//input".format(i)))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please add time.sleep Inside for loop